# Set fields based on sub document aggregates

Tags: mongodb

In the collection below I am trying to calculate `total` / `sold_total` / `sold_percent` by aggregating the `copies` sub doc.

Similarly, I want to calculate `grand_total` / `sold_grand_total` / `sold_grand_percent` by aggregating the `inventory` sub document. 
I prefer to do this during writes/updates  or using a MongoDB function/job instead during 'reads' for efficiency.

I have tried a couple of aggregate pipelines but sub-array unwinding the copies array clears everything above it. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```js
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "store" : "StoreB",
    "grand_total" : 7,
    "sold_grand_total" : 5,
    "sold_grand_percent" : 72,
    "inventory" : [
        {"title" : "BookA", "total" : 4, "sold_total" : 3, "sold_percent" : 75,
            "copies" : [
                    {"_id": 1, "condition": "new", "sold": 1 },
                    {"_id": 2,"condition": "new", "sold": 1 },
                    {"_id": 3,"condition": "new", "sold": 0 },
                    {"_id": 4,"condition": "new", "sold": 1 }
            ] 
        },
        {"title" : "BookB", "total" : 1, "sold_total" : 1, "sold_percent" : 100,
            "copies" : [
                    {"_id": 1, "condition": "new", "sold": 1 }
            ] 
        },
        {"title" : "BookC", "total" : 2, "sold_total" : 1, "sold_percent" : 50,
            "copies" : [
                    {"_id": 1, "condition": "new", "sold": 1 },
                    {"_id": 2,"condition": "new", "sold": 0 }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your mongo document look like? This one you are already doing everything

Comment: The document looks exactly like the one that I listed. But I added the values  total, total_sold, sold_percent and grand_total, sold_grand_total , sold_grand_percent manually. I would like to have these calculated automatically as this doc is updated.  For instance if a  new copy is added like {"_id": 5,"condition": "new", "sold": 0 }. the upsert should update the total / sold_total, sold percent.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of going this. I am not sure what your architecture is.

These are the 2 different aggregates:
This one gives **"total" and "sold_total"**

```
[
    {
        "$unwind" : "$inventory"
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$inventory.copies"
    },
    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$inventory.title", 
            "total": { 
                "$sum": "$inventory.copies.sold" 
            },
           "sold_total": { 
                "$sum": 1 
            }  
        } 
    }]
```

Other gives **grand_total / sold_grand_total**

```
[
    {
        "$unwind" : "$inventory"
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$inventory.copies"
    },
    {
    "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "total": { 
            "$sum": "$inventory.copies.sold" 
        },
       "count": { 
            "$sum": 1 
        }  
    } 
}]
```

You can do both together, by getting the entire object from a group by operation and giving performing the other group by on it. basically, project and pipeline it.